# Need to construct Tables With Column Headings Printed Sideways

Tags: tables

Constructing a table with column headings printed sideways seems like it would be a standard option with any software that can produce tables.  Yet I have not been able to find such an animal anywhere.  Where should I be looking?

Comment: @Ryan - why is this on hold? is it not a fairly straightforward question?

Comment: @Benteh if its asking what software to use (doesn't specify any) then I think its too broad and if its asking for implementation then it shows a lack of effort. But here you go..

Comment: What software, excel, word, indesign, quark, latex...?

Comment: @Benteh sorry, reclosing as it seems I wasn't alone in my original assessment.

Comment: @Hockeybuff  Unfortunately this question is on hold and I can't create a proper answer. How sad. Do you need one column to be sideway... or all of them? In Microsoft Words and Excel, you can create tables and simply go in the menu "format" and then select "text direction" in the rows/cells/columns where you want a different direction. If you want every columns to be sideway... you can simply work in "landscape" orientation and rotate the whole document instead!

Comment: @Ryan fair enough; the community has spoken. I would have liked the OP to specify though, but seems that will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

In **Adobe InDesign** it is just a matter of rotating the text correctly for the leftmost column.

[image]

Comment: How do we lnow he wants to use indesign?

Comment: We don't. But it is software which will work.

Comment: So will excel or word, latex and many many other app.

Comment: @joojaa don't blame **me** for the lack of clarity in the question. I voted to close it. It was reopened.. so I provided an answer.

Comment: @Scott nobody voted to close before I hammered it. If someone had I would've left it shut. Since I was alone and Benteh asked I didn't want to seem a dictator.

Comment: @Ryan.. hmm.. though I had. Well I did vote after you reopened then :)

Comment: I am the OP and regret not having been a little more specific both in software tried and table layout.  Thanks go-me for your insights.  My software at present is limited to Excell (msOffice) so I was hoping for software recommendations, e.g. Adobe.  The table layout I need is for ALL column headings to extend vertically (i.e. sideways printing) except the first column.